# Media Player Classic rmvb compatibility issue in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, codec, media-player-classic, rmvb

I get this error whenever i try to run an rmvb (RealMedia Variable Bitrate) file.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/image.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/image.png)

I've installed K-Lite Codec Pack, DirectX, and Shark codec. Is there a solution?

(When I press OK, another screen just like this one appears; pressing OK again shows a few more details in my language (nothing substantial or informative) and then the video starts very slowly and with no sound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Real Alternative codec. That should fix the problem:

> You do need a player that is capable
>   of playing RealMedia. The included
>   Media Player Classic supports it and
>   works very well. Supported: RealAudio
>   (.ra .rpm), RealMedia (.rm .ram **.rmvb**
>   .rpx .smi .smil), RealText (.rt),
>   ReadPix (.rp), RealMedia embedded in
>   webpages. .smi and .smil files
>   sometimes only play the first part of
>   a clip. This is a limitation of the
>   current Media Player Classic. The
>   RealMedia Browser plugin supports
>   Internet Explorer, Opera, Netscape and
>   Mozilla.